# PWM - What does pwmSetClock() and pwmSetRange() mean?

Tags: pwm, wiringpi

I have looked at the WiringPi site and have found:

```
pwmSetRange (unsigned int range) ;

This sets the range register in the PWM generator. The default is 1024.

pwmSetClock (int divisor) ;

This sets the divisor for the PWM clock.
```

What does that mean? What is the PWM clock and what is meant by "range register".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In digital electronics, especially computing, a [hardware register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_register)
> stores bits of information in such a way that systems can write to or
> read out all the bits simultaneously.

I'm not sure, but [page 139 of this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) sounds like range N and divisor M:

> A value represented as a ratio of N/M can be transmitted along a
> serial channel with pulse width modulation in which the value is
> represented by the duty cycle of the output signal. To send value N/M
> within a periodic sequence of M cycles, output should be 1 for N
> cycles and 0 for (M-N) cycles.

[This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9725/8527) seems to agree.